# show a result after selecting a value of dropdowlist using javascript

Tags: javascript

after surching with no result i come to ask for help
i'm creating a google docs add-on i have created a script that show gmail messages in sidebar

this is the scipt that call the masseges :

```
function getEmails(max) {

  var threads =  GmailApp.search("in:inbox", 0, 500);
  var myMsgs =   "<table>";

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {



    myMsgs+=  "<tr><td>"+ threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject() +"</td></tr>"



  }

  myMsgs += "</table>"

  return myMsgs;


}
```

and this is the function that show messages in sidebar :

```
function getEmails() {

  clearDom();


  var mySelector = document.getElementById("myselector");  
  var valueSelectede = mySelector.options[mySelector.selectedIndex].value;


  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(getEmailsCallback)
  .getEmails(valueSelected);

}
```

and this is the dropdownlist :

```
  <div class="button-bar" style="padding: 10px;background-color:#EEEEEE;width:100%">

    <button id="startButton" class="blue" onclick="getEmails()">Get message(s)</button>

    <button id="groupsButton" class="red" onclick="getGroups()">Get Groups</button>

    <select id="myselector">
      <option value=2 selected="selected">2</option>
      <option value=10>10</option>
      <option value=25>25</option>
      <option value=50>50</option>
    </select>

  </div>
```

How can i show only 2, 10, 25 or 50 messages in the user select number 2, 10, 25 or 50
it would be grateful if you would please take the time to carefully read my probleme and help me to solve it thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is the new working code if someone need it

```
function getEmails() {

  clearDom();


  var mySelector = document.getElementById("myselector");  
  var valueSelected = mySelector.options[mySelector.selectedIndex].value;



  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(getEmailsCallback)
  .getEmails(valueSelected);

}
```

funtion to import e-mails

```
function getEmails(max) {

  var threads =  GmailApp.search("in:inbox", 0, max);
  var myMsgs =   "<table>";

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {



    myMsgs+=  "<tr><td>"+ threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject() +"</td></tr>"



  }

  myMsgs += "</table>"

  return myMsgs;


}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be like this:

```
function getEmails(start, max) {

      var threads =  GmailApp.search("in:inbox", start, max);
      var myMsgs =   "<table>";

      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {



        myMsgs+=  "<tr><td>"+ threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject() +"</td></tr>"



      }

      myMsgs += "</table>"

      return myMsgs;


}
```

---

```
<div class="button-bar" style="padding: 10px;background-color:#EEEEEE;width:100%">

    <button id="startButton" class="blue" onclick="getEmails(0, Number(document.getElementById('myselector').value))">Get message(s)</button>

    <button id="groupsButton" class="red" onclick="getGroups()">Get Groups</button>

    <select id="myselector">
        <option value=2 selected="selected">2</option>
        <option value=10>10</option>
        <option value=25>25</option>
        <option value=50>50</option>
    </select>

 </div>
```

I add the parameter start because you might want to develop the scenario in which you show pagination.

Comment: @Vehaeren thanks for the answer but i got nothing on my add-on with my code i can get all the mails but now nothing =/

Comment: I suppose that's why I got a downvote (well deserve then). What I did was checking the documentation here (see if you have more luck): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String,Integer,Integer)

Comment: the probleme was var valueSelectede i changed it to var valueSelected and  
var threads =  GmailApp.search("in:inbox", 0, 500);
changed to 
 var threads =  GmailApp.search("in:inbox", 0, max);
and then if the user chose a number it will show only the number of msgs than he want to check
i got my answer when i have tried to use you code so thank you @Verhaeren

Comment: Good, now you can test it passing the parameters in my aprroach